# How to get rid of the ruler in the header and footer from the package {fancyhdr}

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I've got this ruler in the header and footer on my first page, I want it to be gone. On the other pages there is a header and footer defined which is working correct but on the first page I just can't remove it.

I've tried to add a custom header to the first page using this:

```
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}
```

But that didn't change anything.

[image: Ruller]

Comment: Where does that ruler come from? Did you redefine the `\headrule` command? In that case add `\renewcommand{\headrule}{}` to your page style.

Comment: I don't know where it came from. I was there suddenly, then again I'm not working constantly on the first page. It happened when I was working on a Gant chart.
I've tried to add `\renewcommand{\headrule}{}` to the top of the tex file But it didn't do anything.

Comment: You have to put that inside the `\fancypagestyle` command. But you should find out where the ruler comes from, because when it is not related to `fancyhdr`, then `fancyhdr` cannot solve it.

Comment: The picture looks like rulers inserted by package `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage` when option `draft` is set.

Comment: possibly related: [koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage: How to get rid of rulers at page edge with when enabling draft class option?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339974/579)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly it was this package that caused it:

```
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
```

After commenting it, the ruler was gone.