# koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage: How to get rid of the rulers at the page edge when enabling the draft class option?

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Is it possible to get rid of these rulers when enabling `draft` class option?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}`

Comment: Is there a way to have my cake and eat it, too? I'd love to make use of the draft status in my headers (so draft=false is not an option), just not have it print that ugly ruler? If not, how does one go about making a feature request? rulers=false can't be impossible to implement ... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339974/koma-script-scrlayer-scrpage-how-to-get-rid-of-rulers-at-page-edge-with-when-en/340008#comment834012_339974)

```
\usepackage[draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```