# Ruler mistakenly being printed at the top and bottom of every page

Tags: koma-script

I have a very big document with a lot of packages. I am using Overleaf. And all of a sudden getting this ruler being printed at the top and bottom of all of my pages, except the title page. Does anyone know which package could be producing this?

[image: Ruler]

Comment: @Mico Not Overleaf's fault I think, any more than it would be e.g. TeXworks' fault. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339974/koma-script-scrlayer-scrpage-how-to-get-rid-of-rulers-at-page-edge-with-when-en

Comment: Great, we'll close as duplicate then.